# android webview: how to intercept form-data when redirect?

Tags: android, webview

I have questions. and sorry my pool english skill.

In android webivew,

I load some page. and this page is redirect another page.

when redirect, url is contain some data(post, form-data).

I want catch contain data. befor loaded url.

I think, override onPageStarted method and catch data. but cannot.

how can I?

```
    private WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        mWebView.postUrl(URL, postdata.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Sample Page
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.log(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private class WebViewClientClass extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        //catch redirect form-data.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below line then only it will use your custom class.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
```

@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

```
//write your code here, get redirected url in this method and do your operation and then move ahead.
return false;
        }
```

Above method will always called when redirect url is getting loaded.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. but, this page is not called shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Comment: I have updated my code please have a look at the updated code and update your current code accordingly.

Comment: yes. I make new WebViewClient and set. but, some redirect url is good work, but some redirect url is not work... :(

Comment: Post your updated code here with which url is not working, because this is not possible as every single url will be called through this method only.